# how to extract the data from pdf and store in excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pypdf

This is the Example of the pdf from which i want to extraxct data.

[image: Sample of pdf]

**This is what i have tried**

```
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
pdfobject=open('w10.pdf','rb')
for i in range(1,pdf.getNumPages()-1):
    print(pdf.getPage(i).extractText())
```

**My Result**
city:Mohali

population 2022

st:456

ID No. 8511

H Code IPRTAHNRE

I Code #5477/7985

Name Sanjeev

Father's Name Ashwani

House No. 121

Age  22

Sex  Male

ID No. 2500

H Code IPWERNER

I Code *2/5464

Name Asdff

Father's Name sgdgd

House No. 154

Age  23

Sex  Male

ID No. 4564

H Code IPRAFHNR

I Code #4577/789

Name Avadhesh

Father's Name Ajor NAth

House No. 12

Age  24

Sex  Male

**Expected Result**

[image: This image is the expected result]

Comment: What's the error? What's the actual vs expected result? And what's the question?

Comment: As a starter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72618062/pypdf-does-not-read-the-pdf-text-line-by-line. .. basically it’s up to you to further process and organize the text you got from the pdf.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please focus on one problem: is it the data extraction from pdf? Is it writing to excel?

Comment: Also, the code you've shared is pretty broken. It defines pdfobject and uses pdf

Comment: @MartinThoma we have to extract the data from the pdf and write it to excel

Comment: I understand that. Please focus on one problem. The fact that you need to use "and" is a clear sign that there are two problems in one question.