# Pdf parsing using pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdf-parsing

While parsing a pdf file using pypdf2, it reads the hifenated words like mm-dd-yy in a newline as :

mm

-

dd

-

yy

This is my code:

```
import PyPDF2    
def getPDFContent(path):
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))    
    content = ""
    content += pdf.getPage(0).extractText() + "\n"    
    return content
```

How can I overcome this and print them in the same line ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017379/pypdf-ignores-newlines-in-pdf-file

Comment: It was not solved yet

Comment: Can anyone help me solve this issue ?