# How to parse text extracted from PDF file with delimiter using Python?

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, pdf-parsing, pypdf

I have tried PyPDF2 to extract and parse text from PDF using following code segment;

```
import PyPDF2
import re

pdfFileObj = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

rawText = pdfReader.getPage().extractText()
extractedText = re.split('\n|\t', rawText)
print("Extracted Text: " + str(extractedText) + "\n")
```

**Case 1:** When I try to parse pdf text, I failed to parse them as exactly as they appear in pdf. For example,

[image]

In this case, line break or new line can't be found in both `rawText` or `extractedText` and results like below-

```
    input field, your old automation script will try to submit a form with missing data unless you update it.Another common case is asserting that a specific error message appeared and then updating the error message, which will also break the script.
```

**Case 2:** And for following case,

[image]

It gives result as-

```
2B. Community Living5710509-112C. Lifelong Learning69116310-122D. Employment5710509-11
```

which is more difficult to parse and differentiate between these individual scores. Is it possible to parse perfectly these scenario with PyPDF2 or any other Python library?

Comment: Check this answer, it may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017379/pypdf-ignores-newlines-in-pdf-file

Comment: This helps every visible separated strings or lines to parse in different new lines using `extractText(Tj_sep="\n")` but yet have to achieve 'Line Spacing' between each paragraph. Thanks btw @Isma